# Git diff on multiple line variable

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to make a git diff between two different revisions of my code.
What is bothering me is the a problem with multi line variable.

Eg.

```
MyVariable= "some_data_here="some_value"; another_data_here \
             more_data_here \
             "
```

When I run:

```
git diff some_commit_sha^! -- repo_name | grep some_data_here
```

The same thing happens without pipe grep.

```
git diff some_commit_sha^! -- repo_name
```

My expectation is to obtain

```
MyVariable= "some_data_here="some_value"; another_data_here \
             more_data_here \
             "
```

Real result are

```
MyVariable= "some_data_here="some_val more_data_here \"
```

How can I make a git diff agains a variable with multiple lines ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is the `!` a typo in your question ? or is it really part of the command you type in your terminal ?

Comment: does `cat yourfile` display the content of your file as you would expect in your terminal ? or does it also "eat up" some lines ?

Comment: @LeGEC. `cat my_file` displays the content of my file as expected.

Comment: Ok. You said you were diffing two revisions : do both versions of the file show up correctly on your terminal ? `git show <rev> path/to/file`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes both of them  are correctly displayed on my terminal.
It's very strange and annoying.

Comment: One last question about potential characters that would mess with your output : what OS and shell are you using ? (eg : linux/bash ? windows/powershell ?)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu / Bash

Comment: Ok. Now to the diff : if you ask `git diff` for more context lines (`git diff -U 9999 <othercommit> -- filename`) : do you see your multiline declaration somewhere (inside or outside a diff chunk) ?

Comment: Yes. I see my multi-line declaration but in the same way , truncated as usual.

Comment: Thank you. It's working with  - - unified=xxx. I don't know why is not working with  - U.   Anyway it's perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git diff -U 9999 <othercommit> -- filename`

Thank you @LeGEC.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Git question — Git outputs the full context. You're piping the output into grep, which will explicitly only output lines which contain the text given as argument. grep doesn't read your code.

You can show lines of context around your grep matches with `-C N` where `N` is number of lines of context. For example:

```
some command | grep -C 5 search term
```

Comment: The same thing happens without grep.

Comment: @Georgian Please provide an example without grep. The output of `git diff` doesn't know to ‘filter’ by a search term, so it will output all changed lines and some lines of context around it.

Comment: I know that but, in my case, when I run git diff I obtain only 69 characters from every line of my multi line variable.
Somehow output is truncated.
I even extended terminal size to 1500/1500 using resize option but the same thing happens and only on multi line variable.
On single line variables, I get full length of  code.